# Currency HTTP Requests

Tags: controllers, action

I have created a custom `controller/action (cart/update_cart)`. Although some clients are making concurrent requests to the API.

I would like to know if Magento has any way of preventing requests from being executed concurrently ? And force them to execute in a queue.

Or would there be any other suggestion to have them run in a queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a mutex lock.  There is no concept of this in Magento (and truthfully, I don't know why you'd want that for a cart operation.  But I'm going to assume you want this for an individual user and not globally.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_SomeController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
  //...some methods

  function yourMethod()
  {
    //...some initiailzation code.
    $_customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();

    //you'd wnat some variation of this if you have guests...
    $lockFileName = sprintf('cart_lock_%s.lock',$_customer->getId());
    $lockFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('tmp_dir').DS.lockFileName;

    if (is_file($lockFilePath )) {
       //file is found, exit!
       return;
    }

    //create lock file
    touch($lockFilePath);

    //continue on
    //....more code

    //remove lock file
    unlink($lockFilePath);
  }

  //...some other methods

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes. I implemented something similar. Yes for a particular user and not global.
Although, I wish I did not have to do it. Although the integration forced me to use this hand
Thanks !